# How to find a syntactic features from a code fragment in a text file?

Tags: java, regex, string, contains

I have code fragments in a text file and have to find out what features (e.g is there a getter/mutator in a line) are associated with a specified line in a code fragment. For example, in a given code fragment

```
1 public HTMLEditor() {
2  //install the source configuration
3  setSourceViewerConfiguration(new HTMLConfiguration());
4  //install the document provider
5  setDocumentProvider(new HTMLDocumentProvider()); }
6 protected void createActions() {
7  super.createActions();
8 //... add other editor actions here
9 }}
```

Line 2,4 and 8 contains a comment and I can check it simply by writing following source code. Let's say

```
public boolean containsComment(String line) {
    // if line contains comment
    if(line.contains("//")){
        return true;            
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Similarly I have to check many such features by writing methods like `containsMutator(string line){//some code here what is it i don't know}`

Some main features are as under:

1. Is there a mutator in a line (setter method)
2. Accessor method (getter method)
3. Does line contain a method
4. contains an exception or not (Both try catch and extends choices)
5. Contains an array
6. Contains a reflection call
7. Contains an anonymous class
8. Call to Java SDK and so on

A line can contain more than one feature e.g line 5 in above snippet has a set method and new keyword too. Also, words such as new or get or etc should only be checked in source code and not in comments part. Same like this there are many such cases; Same as my `containsComment` which is easier to check other features such as exception checking, new or other keywords checking are little trickier and needs some complex code to handle.

What is the best way to check such features? Should I use regex or any other way?

**NOTE:**  I have solved most of the features above with `line.contains()`. Please could someone help me in these i.e., i) Contains a reflection call,

ii) Contains an anonymous class

```
ObjectInterestedInFooObjects() {
   result = someLookup.lookupResult(Foo.class);
    result.addLookupListener(this);
     resultChanged(null);
 }
```

iii) how to check if method or class is referred and call to Java SDK is made.

Comment: Are you looking for a general solution that will work with any Java code, compilable or otherwise?  I'm not aware of any IDE (or IDE plugin) which helps automate this process for an entire file or set of files.

Answer (score 1):

For some of this the approach with `line.contains()` will work.

But how do you e.g determine that something is a setter method? Just by the method signature? 
If not, you would have to parse the respective implementation (that you will most of the time not even have).

So do you want to say "this might be a setter" then you can play with `contains()` and regex.
If you want to say "this IS a setter" you will need a lot more; starting with a clean concept of what makes up a special language feature.

Comment: do you mean `line.contains(".set")` if the line in a fragment is something like this `INSTANCE.setDelegates(new XMLFileSystem(`

Comment: It would work most of the time but would also catch things like `this.setup()`.
My intention was more to get you thinking about what you really want to achieve and how accurate your result should be.
If you don't mind getting the setup() line tagged as setter then you are fine with that

Comment: well no I am more specifically looking for methods in this format `this.setDelegates`